# Old GitHub account still connected in PhpStorm

Tags: git, github, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I had two accounts on my phpstorm (personal and pro).

I deleted the pro account in phpstorm setting and set my personal account as default. I also deleted my pro account on gitHub.

I changed through gitbash user.name and user.email for my personal account and good info appears when i do git config -l command.

However, in git console it's still noticed that the author of commit is pro account and on gitHub the author of commit is still pro account.

I think there is still pro account info somewhere...

How to delete for ever the pro account and just use now my personal account ?

Thanks a lot ;).

I'm using 2023.2.1 phpstorm version.

[image]

Comment: GitHub accounts != Git author information

Comment: Hi, please check: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/troubleshooting-commits/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user